# How to manually register an instance of a provider with angular2 dependancy system

Tags: angular, openfin

I am using Angular2 with OpenFin to build an application. I have a service class which is marked as Injectable and is listed as a provider in NgModule. It is being injected into a component but it is only when the component is created that my service class is instantiated. I would like the service class to be created when the application starts up regardless of whether my component is created but when my component is created the instance I created upfront should be injected into the component.

I suspect what I want to do is create an instance of the service at startup and then pass that to Angular to tell it to use that instance when any component requires it. Is that possible or do I have to rely on Angular to instantiate my service.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a singleton object of the service. You can register your service in `ngModule` decorator of the `rootcompoent`. Then that single instance will be available to be used throughout your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular DI is lazy, but there is one trick make service instantiation eager: you need to implement `OnDestroy` interface.

Comment: OK, great I am not in a position to try that now will report back if that does the job. Thank you.

Comment: Just realised I can try this out on an example app I had on my laptop. This solution actually works, not sure why it does and would interested to know why but it does. Thanks very much.

Comment: This is undocumented feature of angular DI, however official documentation mentions that this callback can be used with services https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnDestroy-class.html

Answer (score 2):

Registering your service in the AppModule's providers meta data will make the service available to any component in the application.

```
import { YourService } from './your-service.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [YourService], // YourService as a provider to the application
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private yourService: YourService){
    this.yourService.Init();
  }
}
```

This is the same a registering a singleton with the container at application start time. Angular will take care of the rest.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue I have is that the service is only instantiated when the first component that requires it is created - what I want is for the service to be created when the app is started regardless of what component, if any, requests it.

Comment: Is your service written to do something that needs to start right away? Or, do you just want the object to be created, no matter what?

Comment: My service is being used by another service running in another process which is why I do not it to depend upon a component in the same process that also needs it requesting it. Ideally I would create an instance of the service pass it to Angular and Angular would pass it to any component in the same process that needs it.

Comment: I see... I added to this. There is now a constructor in the AppModule that asks for the YourService service, and runs an Init function that may, or may not, be there in your service. I know this will compile; the application will run like this. Will it do what you need considering there is another process involved? No idea. :)

Comment: That does work, so thanks very much. The solution Kemsky provided also works and and although I don't understand yet why it works I prefer it as it only needs something to be added to the serrvice.

Comment: I think using the implementation of `OnDestroy` for this purpose is very obscure and might very well break in the future. I believe the answer given by R. Richards is the only correct long-term solution for your use case.

I'd suggest changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this simply register your service in `@ngModule` decorator of the `rootcomponent` as shown below,

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  ...
  providers:[AppService],   //scoped to entire application
  ...
})
```

Now use this service in any component whenever required.

**NOTE** : don't try to use/register `providers:[AppService]` in any individual component. If you try do so, it will create a different instance scoped to that component only.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide it as `APP_INITIALIZER`:

```ts
providers: [{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useClass: YourService, multi: true}],
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html

Comment: I like the look of this. The docs still have this marked as experimental. Any reason to believe it will go away?

Comment: Don't think so, but can't promise ;-)